# Eclipse forgetting repository / repo details

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, store, credentials

I have using Eclipse for a while to push my project repositories to bitbucket.

However, with my current project, it does not remember my remote repo credentials, and I have to manually enter them again each time I want to push my changes.

Cannot find this problem documented elsewhere, so am wondering if there might be a setting I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. In Eclipse, go to...

Window > Preferences > Team > Git

...then tick the 'Store credentials in secure store by default' checkbox beneath 'Secure Store'.